# Using jq to fetch a value with a bracket

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have the following JSON data

```
 "cumulativeStatistics": [
      {
        "Mean_Test_Time_(ms)": 481.6876712328767,
        "Response_bytes_per_second": 10514.456156404525,
        "Errors": 0.0,
        "testNumber": 1.0,
        "TPS": 2.141001049970378,
        "testDescription": "Some status",
        "Mean_time_to_first_byte": 481.1034246575342,
        "Tests": 1460.0,
        "Peak_TPS": 4.0
      },
      {
        "Mean_Test_Time_(ms)": 453.88211103495547,
        "Response_bytes_per_second": 10507.254474105619,
        "Errors": 0.0,
        "testNumber": 2.0,
        "TPS": 2.1395346108950557,
        "testDescription": "Status Again",
        "Mean_time_to_first_byte": 453.4825222755312,
        "Tests": 1459.0,
        "Peak_TPS": 4.0
      }
```

I'm using the following jq that's able to get out every other parameter except Mean_Test_Time_(ms) because of the brackets

```
 cat sample.data | jq '.perf.cumulativeStatistics[0].Response_bytes_per_second'
```

It's interpretting the brackets itself. So when I use Mean_Test_time_(ms) with that command, I get the following error

```
error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting $end
.perf.cumulativeStatistics[0].Mean_Test_Time_(ms)
```

How do I escape these paranthesis?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like in Javascript, you can use brackets to access such "problematic" property names, like this:

```
jq '.perf.cumulativeStatistics[0]["Mean_Test_Time_(ms)"]' sample.data
```